# How to authenticate users in document library in sharepoint 2013 using javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, sharepoint-2013

I need to create a sharepoint hosted extension app that will prompt for user credentials when user wants to upload documents in a document library. Which authentication technique should be used and how to code that in javascript. Will the javascript code for authentication for sharepoint online work in sharepoint 2013 on premises?